# Removing containers ran with docker-compose -f stack.yml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I followed the Drupal docker-compose guidelines on DockerHub and rand the stack.yml file with docker-compose. However I can't seem tm remove it or do anything with it. It might sound stupid but can't figure out what is happening here. Docker-compose rm seems to look for a docker-compose.yml file and not a stack.yml

```
milan@Milans-Air drupal1 % cat stack.yml       
# Drupal with PostgreSQL
#
# Access via "http://localhost:8080"
#   (or "http://$(docker-machine ip):8080" if using docker-machine)
#
# During initial Drupal setup,
# Database type: PostgreSQL
# Database name: postgres
# Database username: postgres
# Database password: example
# ADVANCED OPTIONS; Database host: postgres

version: '3.1'

services:

  drupal:
    image: drupal:8-apache
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html/modules
      - /var/www/html/profiles
      - /var/www/html/themes
      # this takes advantage of the feature in Docker that a new anonymous
      # volume (which is what we're creating here) will be initialized with the
      # existing content of the image at the same location
      - /var/www/html/sites
    restart: always

  postgres:
    image: postgres:10
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
    restart: always%                                                                                                            milan@Milans-Air drupal1 % docker-compose ls -a
NAME                STATUS
drupal1             exited(2)
milan@Milans-Air drupal1 % docker-compose rm drupal1
can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any parent: not found
milan@Milans-Air drupal1 %
```

Comment: How did you start it initially?  If you used `docker-compose -f stack.yaml up` as the title implies, you need the `-f stack.yaml` option in every `docker-compose` command you run.  (Or to rename the file to the standard `docker-compose.yml`.)

Answer (score 0):

renaming the stack.yml file to docker-compose.yml and then running

```
docker-compose down
```

seems to do the trick but that can't be the only/right way to do it